# ViewModel not updating

Tags: knockout.js

I have a problem with my Views in KnockoutJS, when using this:

```html
Account holder: <input type = 'text' data-bind = "value: payer.banking_details()[0] ? payer.banking_details()[0].account_holder: 'unknown'" style = "width: 100%">
```

It doesn't seem to update this:

```html
Account holder: <span data-bind = "text: payer.banking_details()[0] ? payer.banking_details()[0].account_holder: 'unknown'"></span>\>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown us your ViewModels, only your Views. However, I'd hazard a guess that you have some JavaScript errors about the bindings not being parsed in the background, because you're diving into your `payer` ViewModels without invoking them as a function.

If I adjust your Views as follows:

```html
Account holder: 
<input type='text' 
       data-bind="value: payer().banking_details()[0] ? payer().banking_details()[0].account_holder: 'unknown'" 
       style = "width: 100%" />
Account holder: 
<span data-bind="text: payer().banking_details()[0] ? payer().banking_details()[0].account_holder: 'unknown'"></span>
```

And use a ViewModel like this...

```
var holder = function() {
    this.account_holder = ko.observable("J DOE");
}

var person = function() {
    this.banking_details = ko.observableArray();
    this.banking_details.push(new holder());
}

var vm = function() {
    this.payer = ko.observable(new person());
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

...then it all works correctly. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nWRME/) for a demo (edit the field, then leave the input: the span gets updated).

PS. I also changed the last bit of your code (`</span\>` to `</span>`), which may or may not matter.